# PIL unable to getcolors of a PNG Image (Image attached)

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

I am working on a very basic PNG image, but when I try to load it in, it gives all pixels as (0). Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTTVg.png

```
from PIL import Image
myImage = Image.open("Oook1VX.png")
print(myImage.getpixel((0,0)))
print(myImage.getcolors())
```

Output:

```
0
[(2073600, 0)]
```

I want it to be able to see the green? It worked for other images, but not this one. If anyone has any ideas I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

`getcolors()` returns a list of tuples that map colors to numbers (for compression purposes).

In your example, that list of tuples says that the color `2073600` is encoded as `0` in the image. So if `getpixel()` returns `0` that means `2073600`.

`2073600` is [#1fa400](http://www.colorhexa.com/1fa400) in hex, which is the green in your image.

You might benefit from a wrapper like this one that automatically resolves the colors:

```
import struct

class PngImage:
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self._colors = {index: color for color, index in image.getcolors()}

    def getpixel(self, pos):
        color = self._colors[self.image.getpixel(pos)]
        return struct.unpack('3B', struct.pack('I', color))

image = PngImage(Image.open("Oook1VX.png"))
image.getpixel((0, 0)) # => (0x1f, 0x1f, 0x00)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answer Bailey. You say that 2073600 is the green in my image, but the program still outputs [(2073600, 0)] even if the colour is changed to pink. (The image has 2073600 pixels)
If I make the image smaller, it outputs: [(49887, (0, 127, 14))]
Also, when I run your code exactly, it outputs:
    struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 3
Please could I have a bit more help?

Comment: @JimmyCarlos: `getcolors` returns "...[an] unsorted list of (count, pixel) values", so in that respect Bailey is indeed wrong. However: according to various other questions (and you might want to read the documentation and search on Stack Overflow), the functions you use do not work well or at all with *indexed* color images. If your image is indexed and green is color #0, then your results are absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There is now a link to the image in the main post, it's a very simple 1920x1080 rectangle made in Paint.NET, absolutely nothing added.

Comment: @JimmyCarlos: "nothing added", yeah so I noticed. You could have added "1920x1080, 8-bit palette, non-interlaced", which is *exactly* what I had to guess.